# Errors after importing Action Bar Sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

After importing the Sherlock Action Bar library project from existing sources I have errors of course. I then import the support library like I should, check to target 4.0 and min 2.1. Have the compiler on 1.6. But I still have errors that there is no com.actionbarsherlock.r.
And of course in the gen folder there is no R file and I don't know how to generate it. No other errors. I have tried fix project setup and and clean. Nothing works.

Comment: Have tried putting all the external libraries in the "libs" folder and then adding them to build path and then building the project again ?

Comment: Make sure that your project and library project from ABS have set the same build target. It should be 15

Comment: So far I have not even started my project only imported the library to get that ready before starting my own

Comment: Under Build Path, I checked Android 4.0 and Android Dependies on Order/Export and it fixed it...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of performing a clean on just this project, please try:

Project > Clean > Clean All Projects

Also, please try installing the necessary 32bit libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

I found these solutions in a similar question:

[R cannot be resolved error when using ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787288/r-cannot-be-resolved-error-when-using-actionbarsherlock)