# Cannot build actionbarsherlock: BuildConfig cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, adt, android-build

I imported the actionbarsherlock folder into the workspace using "Import -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace". Then I ensured the following:

- In the manifest:

  `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>`
- Properties -> Android: Build target is API 16 (Android 4.1.2) and IsLibrary is checked.
- Properties -> Java Compiler: Compiler compliance level is set to 1.6.

And yet I'm getting a lot of `BuildConfig cannot be resolved to a variable` errors.

I tried to clean all projects many times, and even restarted Eclipse several times. I even tried to add a BuildConfig class manually, but then there were still a lot of `R cannot be resolved to a variable` errors that I could not resolve.

I've read dozens of answers (such as this one: [R cannot be resolved error when using ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787288/r-cannot-be-resolved-error-when-using-actionbarsherlock?rq=1) ), but nothing helps. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Strangely enough, the problem was that I skipped MIPS System Image the last time I updated components in the Android SDK Manager. Now I updated MIPS System Image from revision 2 to 4, and everything builds fine.

I don't even use MIPS, but maybe there was some strange compatibility issue.

Comment: I don't remember specifically, but I just applied all the available updates in the SDK Manager.

Comment: This saved my life! I never had MIPS installed at all, but when I did, it started working again :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the MIPS System Image. It was most probably the SDK Build-tools you updated in the process. I didn't download the MIPS system Image... I only updated the tools. Problem solved. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad updating the tools worked for you, but in my case it was definitely the MIPS image. Your dismissal is quite offensive, I know what I updated.

Comment: In my case SDK Build-tools are already up to date. Installing MIPS System Image fixed my problem. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm sorry. Of course I didn't mean to offend you. I just wanted to state that I think that it's quite unlikely that this is related to the MIPS System Image. Especially because you commented earlier that you "..just applied all the available updates...".

Comment: @MrMaffen Sorry, what I meant to say is that I don't remember the API level, but the only update available for that API level was the MIPS system image. So I wanted to tell Roylee that if he's not sure about the API level, he can just update everything, and it's important not to skip the MIPS system image even if he doesn't use it, because this is what I did initially.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. When I went back to the Android SDK Manager it showed me that I could update Android SDK Platform-tools and Android SDK Build-tools to version 17. That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I can't imagine that updating the MIPS system fixed the problem (although I wouldn't be surprised if it did). I just updated to Build Tools v17 and things started to work again. Wasn't Google IO last week there they darlinged all of their developers?

Comment: same here, after upgrading to android studio 0.4.0 I ran into the same issue. installed android sdk plattform tools 19.0.1 what solved the issue. poor information politics on google side

Answer (score 4):

Strangely enough, this issue gets fixed when I add old flavors of `Android SDK build tools`: 18.x and 17.x

(For some reason, I uninstalled some of those)

[image]

Comment: This should be the answer. It's because these linkages are only in those Build-Tools, removing them and the system can't find them anymore.

Comment: Well, upvoting the hell of the answer in the hopes that it gets displayed more prominently might help other people :)